# I have a stored procedure and I have made it using UNION ; how can I count total number of rows?

Tags: sql, count, union

I need to count total number of rows from a query and that query have union. If I use `Count(*)`, I get an error. So how can I get the count?

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    ProjectName, ProjectReference,
    ProjectID, SiteSupervisor,
    PrincipalContractor, PrincipalDesigner  
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ProjectName, ProjectReference,
         ProjectID, SiteSupervisor,
         PrincipalContractor, PrincipalDesigner 
     FROM  
         CompanyProjects 
     WHERE 
         EndDate < GETDATE()

     UNION 

     (SELECT 
          CompanyProjects.ProjectName AS ProjectName, 
          CompanyProjects.ProjectReference AS ProjectReference, 
          CompanyProjects.ProjectID AS ProjectID,
          CompanyProjects.SiteSupervisor AS SiteSupervisor, 
          CompanyProjects.PrincipalContractor AS PrincipalContractor, 
          CompanyProjects.PrincipalDesigner AS PrincipalDesigner
      FROM 
          CompanyProjects 
      INNER JOIN  
          CompanyCurrentReview ON companyprojects.ProjectID = CompanyCurrentReview.ReviewProjectId 
                               AND CompanyCurrentReview.IsReviewComplete = 0
                               AND CompanyCurrentReview.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()  
                               AND ProjectID NOT IN (SELECT ProjectID 
                                                     FROM CompanyProjects 
                                                     WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()))

     UNION 

     (SELECT 
          ProjectName, ProjectReference,
          ProjectID, SiteSupervisor,
          PrincipalContractor, PrincipalDesigner 
      FROM  
          CompanyProjects 
      WHERE 
          CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
          AND ProjectID NOT IN ((SELECT CompanyProjects.ProjectID
                                 FROM CompanyProjects 
                                 INNER JOIN CompanyCurrentReview ON companyprojects.ProjectID = CompanyCurrentReview.ReviewProjectId AND CompanyCurrentReview.IsReviewComplete = 0
    AND CompanyCurrentReview.DateTime between DateAdd(year,-2,GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()) 
    UNION  SELECT ProjectID FROM  
    CompanyProjects WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()))) As result order by ProjectID desc
```

Comment: What error? Where are you putting the `count(*)` (edit your question, not a comment reply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select count(*) from
(
SELECT ProjectName,ProjectReference,ProjectID,SiteSupervisor,PrincipalContractor,PrincipalDesigner FROM (SELECT  P ro jec tName,ProjectReference,ProjectID,SiteSupervisor,PrincipalContractor,PrincipalDesigner FROM
CompanyProjects WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()

UNION 

(SELECT CompanyProjects.ProjectName As ProjectName, CompanyProjects.ProjectReference As ProjectReference, CompanyProjects.ProjectID As ProjectID,
CompanyProjects.SiteSupervisor As SiteSupervisor, 
CompanyProjects.PrincipalContractor As PrincipalContractor, CompanyProjects.PrincipalDesigner As PrincipalDesigner
FROM CompanyProjects 
INNER JOIN  CompanyCurrentReview ON companyprojects.ProjectID = CompanyCurrentReview.ReviewProjectId AND CompanyCurrentReview.IsReviewComplete = 0
AND CompanyCurrentReview.DateTime between DateAdd(year,-2,GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()  AND ProjectID NOT IN(
SELECT ProjectID FROM  
CompanyProjects WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()
))

UNION 

(SELECT ProjectName,ProjectReference,ProjectID,SiteSupervisor,PrincipalContractor,PrincipalDesigner FROM  
CompanyProjects WHERE CreatedDate  between DateAdd(year,-2,GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE() AND ProjectID NOT IN(
(SELECT CompanyProjects.ProjectID
FROM CompanyProjects 
INNER JOIN  CompanyCurrentReview ON companyprojects.ProjectID = CompanyCurrentReview.ReviewProjectId AND CompanyCurrentReview.IsReviewComplete = 0
AND CompanyCurrentReview.DateTime between DateAdd(year,-2,GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()) 
UNION  SELECT ProjectID FROM  
CompanyProjects WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()))) As result order by ProjectID desc
) a
```

Comment: Happy to help !